# How to create an Autocomplete suggestions with a button inside, and for the click not to propagate into the autocomplete?

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I have a regular `<el-autocomplete>` Element UI input field fetching some results that I would like to add to an array straight from the autocomplete-suggestions. I've added a button to the suggestions but the select event in the autocomplete keeps getting triggered, is there anyway around this ?

Comment: Have you tried applying the event modifiers on your button click?  
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: @TommyF yes the event keep propagating through the parent